Unable to load JSONATA into duktape JavaScript engine
I'm trying to use jsonata for python in a Jupyter notebook running in Visual Studio Code. I have installed jsonata via %pip install jsonata, and have imported it via import jsonata. However, when I try to run a command such as jsonata.Context() or jsonata.transform('x', {'x': 10}), I get the following error message: Unable to load JSONATA into duktape JavaScript engine.
Visual Studio Code version 1.91.1
python 3.12.4
jsonata 0.2.5 (it's the python API's version)
Windows 10 Version 22H2
Computer architecture x64

A workaround: I've switched to another jsonata implementation for python, namely jsonata-python, which is supposedly a pure python implementation of jsonata, and therefore hopefully won't cause interoperability issues.
